# scalatest not working in intellij 13.1

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest, intellij-13

I can't seem to get Intellij 13.1 to run my tests.  I've created a simple project to try and isolate the problem but it is also not working there. Here is my setup:

- Intellij 13.1 Targeting JDK 1.6 (needed for java libraries being used)
- SBT backed scala 2.10 project
- latest scalatest (libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test")

Here is the sut:

```
object Calc {
  def add(a: Int, b: Int) = {
    a + b
  }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class Calc$Test extends FunSuite {
  test("two number should add") {
    assert(Calc.add(2, 5) == 7)
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Error:scalac: 
>        while compiling: /Users/test-user/Development/temp/sample/src/test/scala/Calc$Test.scala
>           during phase: typer
>        library version: version 2.10.4
>       compiler version: version 2.10.4   reconstructed args: -nobootcp -javabootclasspath : -classpath /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javaws.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/management-agent.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/plugin.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/charsets.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/ui.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/apple_provider.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Users/test-user/Development/temp/sample/target/scala-2.10/test-classes:/Users/test-user/Development/temp/sample/target/scala-2.10/classes:/Users/test-user/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/test-user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.2.jar:/Users/test-user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.2.jar:/Users/test-user/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/bundles/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/Users/test-user/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.11/bundles/scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.jar:/Users/test-user/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-reflect.jar:/Users/test-user/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-compiler.jar
>   last tree to typer: Apply(method ==)
>                 symbol: method == in class Int (flags:  )    symbol definition: def ==(x: Int): Boolean
>                    tpe: Boolean
>          symbol owners: method == -> class Int -> package scala
>         context owners: value  -> class Calc$Test -> package 
>   == Enclosing template or block == Template( // val :  in class Calc$Test   "FunSuite" // parents   ValDef(
>       private
>       "_"
>       
>          )   // 2 statements   DefDef( // def (): Calc$Test in class Calc$Test
>       
>       ""
>       []
>       List(Nil)
>        // tree.tpe=Calc$Test
>       Block( // tree.tpe=Unit
>         Apply( // def (): org.scalatest.FunSuite in class FunSuite, tree.tpe=org.scalatest.FunSuite
>           Calc$Test.super."" // def (): org.scalatest.FunSuite in class FunSuite,
>   tree.tpe=()org.scalatest.FunSuite
>           Nil
>         )
>         ()
>       )   )   Apply(
>       Apply(
>         "test"
>         "two number should add"
>       )
>       Apply(
>         "assert"
>         Apply( // def ==(x: Int): Boolean in class Int, tree.tpe=Boolean
>           Calc.add(2, 5)."$eq$eq" // def ==(x: Int): Boolean in class Int, tree.tpe=(x: Int)Boolean
>           7
>         )
>       )   ) )
>   == Expanded type of tree == TypeRef(TypeSymbol(final abstract class Boolean extends AnyVal)) uncaught exception during compilation:
>   scala.MatchError

Any idea what the issue might be?  I assume this is caused by a simple config problem as the code is about as simple as can be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem you clearly have is that you're asking for the version of scalatest compiled for Scala 2.11, but you say you're using Scala 2.10. You need "scalatest_2.10" instead of "scalatest_2.11" in your build.sbt. Use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test"
```

or perhaps even

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"
```

to get your Scala version picked up automatically (note the change to to a double percent: %%.)

Comment: well that was easy :) I thought i read that I could that scalatest with scala 2.10 - I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: I wonder if you're still a bit confused about the difference between the version of a particular API you're using and the Scala version for which a particular package is compiled. In the case of your dependency above, you were requesting version 2.2.1 of the scalatest APIs, and this is available in packages for both Scala 2.10 and Scala 2.11. For scalatest the compiler version is baked into the artifact name, but it's not always done that way. It may be helpful to look at [this listing](http://maven-repository.com/search?q=scalatest).

Answer (score 0):

Since your project is 2.10 backed, use the same version for scalatest too,

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5" // don't need to mention scalatest_2.10, will be reflected automatically

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" // works with 2.2.1 or 3.0.0

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
```

Or using maven,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalactic_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Reference here http://www.scalatest.org/install